# issues in vertically centralization with position absolute

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to centralizing a container. This container has an inner container which in turn has a header, a content and a footer.

What I am trying to achieve is that the parent container has to have the height acordingly to its content, however respecting a limit, a max-height setted.

I tried this in two different ways, neither of them works fully, I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmLm2khd/) to illustrate my point.

if you erase the content step by step, you'll see that despite I have setted only the max-height, the container doesn't get lower, it behaves like a height was setted.

if you change the class of the container to "container-2", you see that despite it gets lower as the content is erased, when the content gets bigger than the parent container, the inner container continues stretching, as if no overflow:auto was setted in the "content" box.

the content box has the editablecontent property setted to be easy to test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        /** just setting some colors **/
        body
        {
            background: red;
        }

        .container
        {
            background: white;
        }

        section
        {
            background: silver;
        }

        header, footer
        {
            background: #ffff0050;
        }
        /** just setting some colors **/

        .container
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;

            margin: auto;

            width: 800px;
            max-height: 80vh;
        }

        .container-2
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%; left: 50%;

            width: 800px;
            max-height: 80vh;

            overflow: hidden;

            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }

        section
        {
            height: 100%;
        }

        header, footer, .content
        {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .content
        {
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: calc(100% - 160px);
        }

        header, footer
        {
            height: 20px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <section>
            <header>
                header
            </header>
            <div class='content' contenteditable=true>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec latine aperiam expetendis ne, eum at numquam interesset, in nec veri posidonium. Id solum aliquip ius. In vix eros debet adolescens, ea pro brute dolores. No ridens vituperata mei. Mei in duis discere ocurreret, autem evertitur signiferumque ut vim. Ne vim erant denique, posse consectetuer qui ut.
                Eos labores pertinax eu, tamquam gloriatur an vim. Et lorem delenit has. Pro lorem latine cu, eu sit omnis scripserit. Mel an case prima, nec petentium adversarium et, per eirmod consequuntur ad.
                At minimum propriae eum, cu assueverit necessitatibus ius. Facer omnium facilisis pri id. Has porro harum id, ne ius ferri aeterno. Zril offendit argumentum ad duo. Ei vel atqui nostro. Ei vim aeque complectitur, id per solet eligendi. Doming efficiantur et ius, usu in tempor denique, sed nisl saepe iisque in.
                Id viderer sensibus corrumpit quo, mea at corpora repudiare reprimique, vix cu indoctum volutpat assueverit. Nominavi scaevola gloriatur ius no, vis ex laudem viderer. Qui utroque maluisset euripidis no. Te regione omnesque vix, debitis sententiae theophrastus vel ad, verear commune incorrupte ad cum. Ei his erant appareat, eum in omnes dolorem sapientem. Te nec doctus volumus abhorreant. Te debitis dolorem democritum mel, duo prodesset abhorreant ne, offendit gubergren eu mei.
                Mel eu solum ancillae torquatos. Et vim doming animal reprimique. Ex per iusto posidonium, et per movet eleifend. Per in quas erant scribentur. Vim veritus eligendi ad, vis stet neglegentur te.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec latine aperiam expetendis ne, eum at numquam interesset, in nec veri posidonium. Id solum aliquip ius. In vix eros debet adolescens, ea pro brute dolores. No ridens vituperata mei. Mei in duis discere ocurreret, autem evertitur signiferumque ut vim. Ne vim erant denique, posse consectetuer qui ut.
                Eos labores pertinax eu, tamquam gloriatur an vim. Et lorem delenit has. Pro lorem latine cu, eu sit omnis scripserit. Mel an case prima, nec petentium adversarium et, per eirmod consequuntur ad.
                At minimum propriae eum, cu assueverit necessitatibus ius. Facer omnium facilisis pri id. Has porro harum id, ne ius ferri aeterno. Zril offendit argumentum ad duo. Ei vel atqui nostro. Ei vim aeque complectitur, id per solet eligendi. Doming efficiantur et ius, usu in tempor denique, sed nisl saepe iisque in.
                Id viderer sensibus corrumpit quo, mea at corpora repudiare reprimique, vix cu indoctum volutpat assueverit. Nominavi scaevola gloriatur ius no, vis ex laudem viderer. Qui utroque maluisset euripidis no. Te regione omnesque vix, debitis sententiae theophrastus vel ad, verear commune incorrupte ad cum. Ei his erant appareat, eum in omnes dolorem sapientem. Te nec doctus volumus abhorreant. Te debitis dolorem democritum mel, duo prodesset abhorreant ne, offendit gubergren eu mei.
                Mel eu solum ancillae torquatos. Et vim doming animal reprimique. Ex per iusto posidonium, et per movet eleifend. Per in quas erant scribentur. Vim veritus eligendi ad, vis stet neglegentur te.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec latine aperiam expetendis ne, eum at numquam interesset, in nec veri posidonium. Id solum aliquip ius. In vix eros debet adolescens, ea pro brute dolores. No ridens vituperata mei. Mei in duis discere ocurreret, autem evertitur signiferumque ut vim. Ne vim erant denique, posse consectetuer qui ut.
                Eos labores pertinax eu, tamquam gloriatur an vim. Et lorem delenit has. Pro lorem latine cu, eu sit omnis scripserit. Mel an case prima, nec petentium adversarium et, per eirmod consequuntur ad.
                At minimum propriae eum, cu assueverit necessitatibus ius. Facer omnium facilisis pri id. Has porro harum id, ne ius ferri aeterno. Zril offendit argumentum ad duo. Ei vel atqui nostro. Ei vim aeque complectitur, id per solet eligendi. Doming efficiantur et ius, usu in tempor denique, sed nisl saepe iisque in.
            </div>
            <footer>
                footer
            </footer>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Do you know a way to get the two things working together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.container-2` and after that need to replace this -

`.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 160px);
}`

with this

`.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: calc(80vh - 160px);
}`

Comment: it worked, I missed max-height. Thank you very much.